# djextListTextBox Select all option in XPages

Tags: xpages

is it possible to add "Select All" and "Deselect All" I could not find how to manage that kind of problem ?

```
<xe:djextListTextBox id="FieldOne" value="#{document1.FieldOne}" rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}" multipleSeparator="," multipleTrim="true">
</xe:djextListTextBox>
 <xe:valuePicker id="vPicIlgiDosyaSec"
                            for="FieldOne" 
                            rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}"
                            dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerCheckbox">
                            <xe:this.dataProvider>
                                <xe:simpleValuePicker
                                    caseInsensitive="true">
                                    <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript: 
}]]></xe:this.valueList>
                                </xe:simpleValuePicker>
                            </xe:this.dataProvider>


                        </xe:valuePicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the Value Picker, but that's not going to be straightforward. Deselect All would be relatively straightforward code behind the scenes (get the `for` component and clear the value). Select All would have to take into account the wide variety of dataProviders, so would be considerable less straightforward.

The easiest option is to store your simpleValuePicker's options somewhere outside the picker itself, then add two buttons to your XPage, Select All would call `document1.replaceItemValue("FieldOne",allVals)`, Deselect All would call `document1.replaceItemValue("FIeldOne","")`.